# wpf 3d, multiple instances of a Model3DGroup, trying to optimize performance

Tags: wpf, performance, 3d

My program shows a static scene containing several instances, at different places, of a 3d model, for example a tree. This model can be 'heavy', between 50000 and 100000 triangles, and the performance degrade quickly with the number of instances (performance is unacceptable with more than 10 instances).

My first code, without optimizations, looks like this :

```
   public partial class Vue3D : Window
   {
    public ModelVisual3D modelVisual = new ModelVisual3D();
    public Model3DGroup model3DGroup = new Model3DGroup();

    public Vue3D()
      {
        ...
        modelVisual.Content = model3DGroup;
        view1.Children.Add(modelVisual); // view1 = viewport3D
        ...
        BuildScene();
      }

    void BuildScene()
      {
        Model3DGroup model = GetModel("tree");
        foreach (Point3D pnt in <point collection>)
        {
          Model3DGroup modelClone = model.Clone();
          Transform3DGroup tg = new Transform3DGroup();
          tg.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform3D(pnt.X, pnt.Y, pnt.Z>)); 
          modelClone.Transform = tg;
          model3DGroup.Children.Add(modelClone);
        }
      }
  }
```

For each instance i clone the complete model, and add the clone to the viewport after transformation.
Let's say the tree model contains 2 GeometryModel3D :
{mesh1 (20000 triangles), texture1} and {mesh2 (40000 triangles), texture2}.
If i show 10 trees, i'm adding 20 GeometryModel3D.

Since all these instances share the same 2 textures, i thought i could speed up things by creating only 2 GeometryModel3D : one with all the triangles associated with texture1, one with all the triangles associated with texture2. That's what i tried in this code :

```
void BuildScene()
  {
    List<Transform3DGroup>> listTg = new List<Transform3DGroup>();
    foreach (Point3D pnt in <point collection>)
    {
      Transform3DGroup tg = new Transform3DGroup();
      tg.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform3D(pnt.X, pnt.Y, pnt.Z>)); 
      listTg.Add(tg);
    }
    Model3DGroup model = GetModel("tree");
    foreach (GeometryModel3D gmodel in model.Children)
    {
      MeshGeometry3D mesh = gmodel.Geometry as MeshGeometry3D;
      GeometryModel3D newgmodel = new GeometryModel3D();
      newgmodel.Material = gmodel.Material;
      newgmodel.BackMaterial = gmodel.BackMaterial;
      MeshGeometry3D newmesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
      newgmodel.Geometry = newmesh;
      foreach (Transform3DGroup tg in listTg)
      {
        foreach (int indice in mesh.TriangleIndices)
          newmesh.TriangleIndices.Add(indice + newmesh.Positions.Count);
        foreach (Point3D p3 in mesh.Positions)
          newmesh.Positions.Add(tg.Transform(p3));
        if (mesh.TextureCoordinates != null)
        {
          foreach (System.Windows.Point p in mesh.TextureCoordinates)
            newmesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(p);
        }
      }
      newmesh.TriangleIndices.Freeze();
      newmesh.TextureCoordinates.Freeze();
      newmesh.Positions.Freeze();
      newgmodel.Material.Freeze();
      newgmodel.BackMaterial.Freeze();
      newgmodel.Freeze();
      model3DGroup.Children.Add(newgmodel);
    }
  }
```

And the performance is not better, in fact it's rather worse ... What am I missing here ? It seems that my assumption, i.e. minimizing the number GeometryModel3D would be beneficial, is false. I have read somewhere that in wpf 3d, the number of triangles has no big impact on performance, but that the number of textures was more critical. Here i have a big number of triangles but only 2 textures, only one ModelVisual3D, and all is frozen... Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck with detaching the mesh applying any transformations and then reattaching the mesh afterward. I got the idea from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613553.aspx

Comment: if's not a problem of transformations; the function BuildScene(), where i add models in the viewport, is called only once, to create a static scene; by static, i mean once the viewport is displayed, its content does not change, only the camera moves.
I know the article pointed by your link, in fact it's there i read that 
"Create different models only when they require different Materials or Transforms. Otherwise, try to coalesce many GeometryModel3D instances with the same Materials and Transforms into a few larger GeometryModel3D and MeshGeometry3D instances."

Comment: Well depending on exactly how big, by this I mean size on screen, the objects are and how much of them you can see at any given point in time. What I mean is if your objects are being dynamically clipped by the viewport3d then you are going to have issues with animations being slow or flickering. This includes the animations of the camera moving around. Honestly I think your best bet may be to move to Direct X at the very least managed DX.